# Nginx forward proxy without redirecting

Tags: nginx

To get around some CORS issues, I'd like to configure an existing nginx server of mine to proxy requests onwards. For example, if my server is at `https://proxy.example.com`, I'd like to be able to use a URL like `https://proxy.example.com/google.com` to get the page and/or content.

The issue I'm running into is that Nginx seems to be giving me `301` redirects, rather than truly proxying the request. This will not do as it's subject to the exact same CORS limitations that I started with. I need the content to flow through my proxy, not redirect the client.

Here's the config I'm working with at the moment. My Nginx knowledge is quite limited, so it's certainly possible there's some weirdness/incorrect stuff beyond my immediate problem:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name proxy.example.com;

    # Strips leading / from request path
    location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
        # Needs to come first
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://$1$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

I've done quite a bit of reading, and there's been all sorts of suggested options and headers (`proxy_redirect`, `Host`, `X-Forwarded-For`, etc.), but none of them have seemed to have any positive effect (a couple seemed to cause issues with Cloudflare, when the proxied sites used it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was that the incoming request was `https`, but the `proxy_pass` was simply `http`. I did this as I was running into a SSL error and thought it a quick solution, but it turns out there's an option to fix this:

```
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```

Once I added this, I could alter the `proxy_pass` value to use `https` and then no longer was the client redirected. Full config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name proxy.example.com;

    # Strips leading / from request path
    location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
        # Needs to come first
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass https://$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
}
```